# Djangoのデータベースに外部からデータを入れたい

Tags: python, django

Djangoで作ったプロジェクトに外部のmaster.pyからデータベースにデータを入れたい。
開発環境ではSQLite 3で本番環境ではMySQLを使用

検索エンジンで調べた結果

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lovadeck.settings")
```

のように記述すればよいとの記述を発見し、試しましたがダメでした。

master.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "lovadeck.settings")
import django
django.setup()
from cms.models import Servant

-------中略---------

Servant.hpf     = servant_divs[1].text #整数の3桁数字が入っています
Servant.hpf20   = servant_divs[2].text
Servant.apf     = servant_divs[4].text #整数の2-3桁の数字が入っています
Servant.apf20   = servant_divs[5].text
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Servant(models.Model):
    '''使い魔'''
    hpf    = models.IntegerField('HP')
    hpf20  = models.IntegerField('HP Lv20')
    apf    = models.IntegerField('AP')
    apf20  = models.IntegerField('AP Lv20')
```

.
├── lovadeck
│   ├── cms
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── lovadeck
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│ 　├── db.sqlite3 
│   ├── manage.py**
│   └── **master.py**
└── Vagrantfile

```
pip freeze -l

beautifulsoup4==4.4.0
distribution==1.0.0
Django==1.8.3
lxml==3.4.4
```

ディレクトリ構造やインストールされているものは以上のようになります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: servant_divs[n].text は unicode型なので int()を使いint型に変換します。助言ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.environ.setdefault`と`django.setup()`は問題ないと思われます。

`Servant`のフィールドに値を代入した後`save()`を行っていないので、データが生成されないのではないでしょうか。

```python
s = Servant()
s.hpf     = servant_divs[1].text
s.hef20   = servant_divs[2].text
s.apf     = servant_divs[4].text
s.apf20   = servant_divs[5].text
s.save()
```

もしくは、`create()`を使っても良いかと。

```python
s = Servant.objects.create(
    hpf=servant_divs[1].text, hef20=servant_divs[2].text,
    apf=servant_divs[4].text, apf20=servant_divs[5].text
)
```

もし`servant_divs[n].text`が`str`や`unicode`型なら`int`型に変換してから代入する必要がありますね。